prove that n! +1 is not always prime.
Ok so I know this is a silly question and I know that for many values of n (for example 4) n!+1 is not prime but I do not know how to write a formal proof for this. Can someone help me?

What proof? If you have an example, this is all what you need.

Please take a [tour] on what constitutes a good question on MSE. As it is right now, this reads like a Do-My-Homework-For-Me . No good

I think this reflects a basic misunderstanding.  A single counterexample is all you need to refute a claim.  Taking $n=5$ we see that $5!+1=121=11^2$ is a counterexample.  Now, you could ask for a proof that, say, there are infinitely many $n$ for which $n!+1$ is not prime, for which see, e.g., this

@Mike I am sorry if this sounds like a "Do-My-Homework-For-Me" question but this is not even my homework. I just wanted to know whether there is a formal as in systematic method to prove this using perhaps modular arithmetic. But I guess that's not allowed here according to you. Thank you for wasting your time on my "Do-My-Homework-For-Me" question

May be worth noting:  as far as I am aware, it is unknown whether or not there are infinitely many $n$ for which $n!+1$ is prime.   Seems like a very difficult problem.

Why is this downvoted? It is clearly not a Do-My-Homework-For-Me question as the author has shown their work. Now it may be an easy question for most people on this forum, but as far as I'm aware there is no requirement that the questions are "hard".

Known values of $n$ such that $n!+1$ is known to be prime are tabulated here. From this it's evident that $n!+1$ being prime is the rarer case. The comments are also of interest: for instance, they note (via Wilson's theorem) that $n!+1$ being prime (and $n>2$) implies $(n+1)!+1$ is not prime.

@Semiclassical thank you for mentioning wilson's theorem. This also proves that there are infinite such composites since there are infinite primes.
